# global name '...' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

what are the differences in `example1`, `example 2` and `example 3`. i have tried but got nothing. i think i have missed something or haven't used correctly.

example 1:

```
def ex1(var1=g_var):
    pass

def ex2():
    global g_var
    g_var = True
    ex1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex2()
```

example 2:

```
def ex1():
    print(g_var)
    # pass

def ex2():
    global g_var
    g_var = True
    ex1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex2()
```

example 3:

```
g_var = True

def ex1(var1=g_var):
    pass

def ex2():
    ex1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex2()
```

it seems that `example 1` and `example 3` are same thing.

`example 2` and `example 3` runs good. but `example 1` give me the error `NameError: global name 'g_var' is not defined`.

Answer (score 3):

Default Values are evaluated at time of definition. At this time, `g_var` isn't defined in example 1.

Comment: Note this is closely related to a common "gotcha" in python, the [mutable default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)